# Where query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, devise

I have a rails application with two tables. One is the users (devise model), with email and password. The other is products that belongs_to users.

When an user login on the app (with his email and pass), I want my product controller to filter so the logged in user can only see the products registered by other users who share the EXACT SAME  EMAIL DOMAIN of the  currently logged in user (current_user).

For example:

- Login as: test@gmail.com
- Products visible:

  - Registered by: test2@gmail.com
  - Registered by: test3@gmail.com
- Products NOT visible:

  - Registered by:  test4@yahoo.com
  - Registered by: test5@yahoo.com

Is it possible? I know about the .where method, but I'm struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
email_domain = current_user.email.split("@").last 
@products = Products.joins(:users).where("users.email like ?", "%#{email_domain}")
```

The first line gets the email domain.
Second line does the checks between `user.email`s and a partial of `email_domain`. The key character here is `%` which is used as a wildcard.

Comment: Hey @amoks. Tks for the answer, but it still doesn't work because it tries to find a 'user.email' on my product table - ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.email).

Comment: @ale It was close -- added the join and updated the where clause.

Comment: Ah yes! thanks @dbugger. Totally forgot the join .

Comment: Tks for the help @amoks and @dbugger!! One last thing, i was wondering how to make it impossible to access the products of another domain directly through the URL.

Comment: @Ale, in show action, `@product = Products.joins(:users).where("users.email like ?", "%#{email_domain}").find(params[:id])`